# Can Terraria on mobile devices play multiplayer games?

Tags: terraria

My sister and I would like to play terraria together, me on my Samsung tablet and her on her Microsoft surface pro. However, neither of us know how to host, or join a game, can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

I do not actually own the mobile version of Terraria, but according to the official wiki (http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mobile_version#Notes), *"Different platforms (PC/Playstation/Xbox/Android/iPhone/Windows Phone) generally cannot play multiplayer games together."*

But, since your sister is on a surface pro, and that runs Windows 8.1, you should be able to play together if you have another PC in the house.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can but you have to be using the same wi fi so sta or sit next to each other and join your sis's game

Answer (score -2):

No. My sons on there tablets have tried this and it does not work. Sorry.